# wikipedia api: get parsed introduction only

Tags: php, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Using PHP, is there a nice way to get the (parsed) introduction *only* from a wikipedia page?

I have to current methods:

- The first is to call the api page and return, then call the Wiki parser on the introduction I have pulled from the first request (two requests, extracting the intro from the text isn't pretty either).
- The second is to call the entire page parser and use `xpath` to retrieve every `<p>` tag before the contents table.

With both methods I then have to re-parse the HTML to ensure the relevant links inside the introduction link off to wikipedia.

Neither are ideal really, there must be a better way?

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext
- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action=parse` API module accepts a section number parameter, [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Computer+programming&prop=text&section=0). The lead is section number 0.